# how to retrieve information from three tables in below conditions in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have three tables.

TABLE_1:

```
T2_ID   ver          date                         boolean
---------------------------------------------------------
  1  | X-20-50 | 2019-01-01 16:20:51.722336+00 | TRUE 
  2  | X-50-30 | 2019-02-26 16:20:51.722336+00 | TRUE
  3  | X-20-32 | 2019-03-20 16:20:51.722336+00 | FALSE
  1  | X-20-50 | 2019-01-09 16:20:51.722336+00 | FALSE
  2  | X-20-50 | 2019-12-02 16:20:51.722336+00 | TRUE
  3  | X-20-50 | 2019-01-24 16:20:51.722336+00 | TRUE
```

TABLE_2:

```
id | type | scheduler
--------------------------------------------------
1  | ABC  | w1,w2,w3,w4,w5,w6,w7,w8,w9,w10,w11,w12
2  | PQR  | w5,w9
3  | TRC  | w1,w4,w8
```

TABLE_3

```
    start_date_of_ver  |    end_date_of_ver     | ver_name
-----------------------------------------------------------
2019-01-01 00:00:00+00 | 2019-04-01 00:00:00+00 | X-20-50
2019-02-25 00:00:00+00 | 2019-05-26 00:00:00+00 | X-50-30
2019-03-15 00:00:00+00 | 2019-06-06 00:00:00+00 | X-20-32
```

Table 4 should fulfill the below condition.

- it takes version name (ver_name) as input
- from this (ver_name), it takes start date and end date of version (**from table_3**) if the version period is 3 months then it creates 12 weeks table with id (type) as the first column and creates an entry of twelve-week according to table 2 of the scheduler.
- information on table 4 will be updated as and when table 1 has entries of that particular week which are TRUE

Note: table 1, entries get generates on a daily basis.

Desired table: which has only **ver_name** as input and calculate below table.

**When table_1 don't have any entries then table_4 should look like as below**

Table_4: X-20-50

```
id_of_table_2 | week_1 | week_2 | week_3 | week_4 | week_5 | week_6 | week_7 | week_8 | week_9 | week_10 | week_11 | week_12 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     ABC      |    w1  |    w2  |    w3  |    w4  |    w5  |    w6  |    w7  |    w8  |    w9  |    w10  |    w11  |    w12  |
     PQR      |        |        |        |        |    w5  |        |        |        |    w9  |         |         |         |
     TRC      |    w1  |        |        |    w4  |        |        |        |    w8  |        |         |         |         |
```

**When table_1 has entries then table_4 should look like as below**

X-20-50

```
id_of_table_2 | week_1 | week_2 | week_3 | week_4 | week_5 | week_6 | week_7 | week_8 | week_9 | week_10 | week_11 | week_12 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     ABC      |  Done  |  Done  |    w3  |    w4  |    w5  |    w6  |    w7  |    w8  |    w9  |    w10  |    w11  |    w12  |
     PQR      |        |        |        |        |    w5  |        |        |        |    w9  |         |         |         |
     TRC      |  Done  |        |        |    w4  |        |        |        |    w8  |        |         |         |         |
```

Comment: Assuming your date column called date, what's wrong with: `select * from <table> where date >= '2019-11-23 09:20:14.419+00' and date < '2019-12-02 16:20:51.722336+00' ORDER BY date ASC;`

Comment: each time user needs to specify dates explicitly if we have huge amount of data i.e. of year and more.

Comment: So if it's going to be a script that runs once a week at the same time - you could just calculate the date to start with until `now()`

Answer (score 0):

You can create function which can take starting date of a week as input.

Example-

```
create function a(start_date) 
RETURNS json
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
COST 100
VOLATILE 
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
 outputjson json;
BEGIN
 EXECUTE 'select json_agg(*) from table_name where date >= '||start_date||' and (date '||start_date||' + integer ''7'')' into outputjson;

RETURN outputjson;
END;
$$
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement needs a little refinement. You specify to retrieve weekly data yet  fail to define a your week. On what day does it begin? Are all weeks 7 days long? What happens when Dec 31 falls on Tuesday is Friday Jan 3 in the same week (see current year calendar). Then there is the issue of user input and what it represents. Is it the desired start date and the week is that date and the next 6 days or any date within weekly period?  
The following assumes an ISO 8601 definition (google it - lots of stuff). Every week begins on Monday and all weeks are 7 days long. (Thus the week containing 31-Dec-2019 also includes 3-Jan-2020). The routine extracts the ISO Year and ISO week user entered date.

```
--setup
 create table  weekly_something( c1 text, c2 text, date1 timestamptz, someem boolean);   
 insert into weekly_something( c1, c2, date1, someem )  
      values ('ABC','AB-20-50','2019-11-25 16:20:51.722336+00',TRUE) 
           , ('PQR','AB-50-30','2019-11-26 16:20:51.722336+00',TRUE)
           , ('TRC','CD-20-32','2019-11-27 16:20:51.722336+00',FALSE)
           , ('ABC','AB-20-50','2019-12-02 16:20:51.722336+00',FALSE)
           , ('ABC','AB-20-50','2019-12-02 16:20:51.722336+00',TRUE) 
           , ('JFF','yy-45-89','2019-12-31 16:20:51.722336+00',TRUE)
           , ('JFF','yy-89-30','2020-01-03 16:20:51.722336+00',TRUE) ;          
            -- JFF Just For Fun

-- SQL Function
create  function week_of(week_date date)
returns setof weekly_something
language sql stable strict
as $$
    select *
      from weekly_something 
     where (extract('isoyear' from week_date), extract('week' from week_date)) =
           (extract('isoyear' from date1), extract('week' from date1));
$$;

-- test
select * from week_of('2019-11-26');
select * from week_of('2019-12-30');
```